# Odoo v11 how can i get Many2many Fields in my view so i can Write on them

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

i want to fill those fields in my datagrid or many2many fields without been forced to go another formula i wanna just do it from there [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCfII.png)

Instead of This
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQKuz.png)
Post Edited /
 I have added editable but still not giving me to write on the same form one i click the add element they redirect to another formula 
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdu4x.png)

Comment: Please add more information and code. What have you tried so far? SO users aren't clairvoyants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`editable="bottom"` as tree property is the solution

if you define your field in your view, define a tree inside with the above property:

```
<field name="one2many_ids">
<tree string="Theese are the list items" editable="bottom">
    <field name="field_1"></field>
    ...
</tree>
```

Comment: Could you a minimum of an explanation?

Comment: Hello i'v tried it but i dont know where im i making a mistake

Comment: iv done that but still giving me the other class formule

Comment: what, if you give your Many2many-Field  a widget property: widget="one2many"?